# Google Cloud Storage Transfer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We’ve been using `Google Cloud Storage Transfer` service and in our `data source` (AWS) we had a directory accidentally deleted, so we figured it would be in the `data sink` however upon taking a looking it wasn’t there despite `versioning` being on.

This leads us to believe in `Storage Transfer` the option [deleteObjectsUniqueInSink](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec#TransferOptions) *hard* deletes objects in the `sink` and removes them from the archive.

We'e been unable to confirm this in the documentation.

Is GCS Transfer Service's [deleteObjectsUniqueInSink](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec#TransferOptions) parameter in the `TransferSpec` mutually exclusive with GCS's object versioning soft-delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the [deleteObjectsUniqueInSink](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec#TransferOptions) option is enabled, `Google Cloud Storage Transfer` will

1. List only the **live** versions of objects in source and destination buckets.
2. Copy any objects unique in the source to the destination bucket.
3. Issue a versioned delete for any unique objects in the destination bucket.

<s>If the unique object is still live at the time that `Google Cloud Storage Transfer` issues the deletion, it will be archived.  If another process, such as [Object Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle), archived the object before the deletion occurs, the object could be permanently deleted at this point rather than archived.</s>

Edit: Specifying the version in the delete results in a hard delete ([Objects Delete Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/delete)), so transfer service *is* currently performing hard deletes for unique objects.  We will update the service to instead perform soft deletions.

Edit: The behavior has been changed. From now on deletions in versioned buckets will be soft deletes rather than hard deletes.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Not that I know of, the [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) is the closest documentation that I'm aware of.